# Best way to get result from Activity in Android API < 16

Tags: android

According to the documentation, it appears the preferred contemporary way to get a result from an activity is by using [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). However, it also appears that the minimum API for this call is 16.

My app has base API 11. What other method would be the preferred way of starting an activity and retrieving a result from it, while satisfying my API baseline?

Comment: `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` has been around since API level 1. Go ahead and use it. It's only the three-argument version (that takes a `Bundle` as a third argument) that's new to API level 16.

Comment: @TedHopp, Please post your comment as an answer.  It's correct.

Comment: Corrected, thanks. This may be an issue with my IDE (IntelliJ 13.0.2), which reports the call as an error with: "Call requires API level 16 (current min is 11): android.app.Activity#startActivityForResult"

Comment: Please post the code that gives this error.

Comment: @Code-Guru: It is simply: Intent snapIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(snapIntent, 1, null);

Comment: Just get rid of the `, null` in the argument list and the IDE should stop complaining.

Comment: You are sending three arguments. Remove the `null` from the last argument and you will be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` has been around since API level 1. Go ahead and use it. It's only the three-argument version (that takes a `Bundle` as a third argument) that's new to API level 16.

Answer (score 3):

[StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) has been added in API level 1.